# Text processing of an HTTP link in Python

Tags: python

Imagine that I have url

```
http://www.google.com/subdomain/blah-blah.../.. /..
```

So I want to extract 4 things from this
1) The Protocol: "http"
2) "www"
3) domain name : google"
4) "com" portion
5) subdomain par: all those after .com part
But as you can see this link can be anything

```
ftp://google.net/hola-hola
```

now this might also be a valid link.
So how do I extract these various portions of url using python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See urlparse.

http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html